# Did Rashi know about radio waves?

Tags: rashi, science

My father told me that he was taught a Rashi in school that suggests that Rashi knew about radio waves.

What Rashi might hint to this conclusion?

Comment: http://jewishnews.com/2014/12/07/did-king-solomon-know-about-radio-waves-almost-3000-years-ago/

Comment: Moshe Rabeinu had a pelephone as Hashem spoke to him "from between the *keruvim*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your father is referring to Bemidbar 7:89. There, the passuk tells us that whenever Moses entered the Tent of Meeting he would hear the voice of God speaking with him, only the word for "speaking" (מדבר) is spelled abnormally. Instead of a *shewa* under the *mem*, there's a *chireq* under the *mem* and a dagesh in the *daled*.

Some grammarians, like Ibn Ezra, see it as a contraction of מן דבר: that Moses heard God *as a result of* his speaking to him, but Rashi disagrees. Rashi reads the dagesh as indicative of an assimilated *tav*: מתדבר. In Rashi's words, this indicates that God was conversing with *himself* (kind of like a background chatter to the universe), and Moses' skill was an ability to tune in (if you will) and listen in.

Here is the passuk, followed by Rashi's comment:

> וּבְבֹ֨א מֹשֶׁ֜ה אֶל־אֹ֣הֶל מֹועֵד֮ לְדַבֵּ֣ר אִתֹּו֒ וַיִּשְׁמַ֨ע
>   אֶת־הַקֹּ֜ול מִדַּבֵּ֣ר אֵלָ֗יו מֵעַ֤ל הַכַּפֹּ֨רֶת֙ אֲשֶׁר֙
>   עַל־אֲרֹ֣ן הָעֵדֻ֔ת מִבֵּ֖ין שְׁנֵ֣י הַכְּרֻבִ֑ים וַיְדַבֵּ֖ר אֵלָֽיו׃
>
> מדבר: כמו מתדבר. כבודו של מעלה לומר כן מדבר בינו לבין עצמו ומשה שומע
>   מאליו

My translation:

> Like *mitdabber*. It is out of respect for God that the passuk is
>   worded thus: [the voice of God] was speaking to itself and Moses was
>   listening in.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen references to a spiritual explanation of this concept.That is, rather than explicitly stating that Rashi knew about radio and television, it is a spiritual meaning of unseen forces. Similarly, the statement that Adam Harishon could see from one end of the world to the other. The medrashim about k'fitzas haderech (teleportation) as experienced by Eliezer on his way to meet Rivkah., etc.

[Rosh Hashana Dvar Torah](https://theshmuz.com/Weekly_Parsha_Printed_Version/WeeklyParsha_Rosh_Hashana_5776.pdf)

> On his last day of life, Moshe Rabbeinu  addresses  the  Klal 
>   Yisrael.   After  a  thorough  explanation  of   the  vast  rewards 
>   and  ghastly  punishments   that  hinge  on  the  choices  made,  he 
>   offers   a final note: Let the heavens and the earth  bear witness.
>
> Rashi explains that Moshe was giving them  a tool to help them stay on
>   the proper path.  “Look at the heavens and the earth did they  change 
>   their  ways?  Did  the  sun  ever  say,  ‘I   won’t  rise  this 
>   morning?’  Did  the  ground   ever say, ‘I won’t produce?’ Or did it
>   say, ‘I  will grow wheat instead,” when you planted  barley?  As  they
>   dutifully  follow  Hashem’s   commands, so too should you.”
>
> In  our  modern  world  we  regularly  harness   forces that our eyes
>   don’t see. No human has  ever seen electricity. We can see the burning
>   of  impurities  in  the  air  as  lightening  streaks   across the
>   sky. But the flow of electric current  is  not  visible
>
> We don’t see radio waves. We don’t see Wi- fi. We don’t see electron.
>   But they exist. And  we know it.
>
> This seems to be the answer to this Rashi. The  Jewish People then
>   were on the highest spiritual level of any generation. They
>   experienced  all  of  the  miracles  in   mitzraim .  They  lived
>   through  the  splitting  of  the  sea.  They  were   there at the foot
>   of Har Sinai, when Hashem  spoke. The heavens were opened up and they 
>   witnessed things that no other people saw.  And  so  they  had  an 
>   understanding  of  the   ways of the world that we don’t. As we know 
>   electricity  exists,  they  knew  the  spiritual   counterpart exists.
>   To them it was real.